I can't figure out why the flash() in flask-admin isn't showing for this specific case, while showing for others
I have been stuck with this problem for two days and I cant figure out why, when I use this method to generate the flash_message on flash_message2 and flash_message3 it works fine and it shows, when I attempt to return my actual one that I intend to return the flash_message the flash message doesn't even show up, this is my code:
def generate_briefing_report(all_data_list, invalids_list, identifier_field: str, title: str = "Report",
                         operation_title="Operation Summary:", button_enabled=True):
formatted_operation_summary_top_message = ""

# All Valid OR partial valid
calculated_disparity = len(all_data_list) - len(invalids_list)
if calculated_disparity == len(all_data_list) or (
        calculated_disparity > 0 and calculated_disparity < len(all_data_list)):
    formatted_operation_summary_top_message += f"[✔] Number of successful operations: {calculated_disparity}"

# All are invalid OR partial Invalid
copyable_erroneous_values = None
if calculated_disparity == 0 or (calculated_disparity > 0 and calculated_disparity < len(all_data_list)):
    if formatted_operation_summary_top_message:
        formatted_operation_summary_top_message += "<br/>"

    formatted_operation_summary_top_message += f"[❌] Number of unsuccessful operations: {len(invalids_list)} "
    copyable_erroneous_values = ", ".join(record["order_number"] for record in invalids_list)

operation_summary_message = Markup(formatted_operation_summary_top_message)
valid_total = calculated_disparity
invalid_total = len(invalids_list)

copy_failed_button_html = ""
if button_enabled and copyable_erroneous_values:
    copy_failed_button_html = f"""
                    <button style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #f0f0f0;" onclick="var textArea = document.createElement('textarea'); textArea.value = '{copyable_erroneous_values}'; document.body.appendChild(textArea); textArea.select(); document.execCommand('Copy'); textArea.remove(); showToast();">Copy Failed to clipboard </button>
                    """ if invalid_total > 0 else ""

data_list = []
for index, record in enumerate(invalids_list, start=1):
    data_list.append([index, record[identifier_field], record["error"]])

settings = {
    "title": title,
    "identifier_title": identifier_field
}

error_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
session[error_id] = {
    'settings': settings,
    'data': data_list
}

report_url = url_for('error_report', error_id=error_id)
open_errors_view_button_html = Markup(f"""
                    <button style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #f0f0f0;" onclick="window.open('{report_url}', '_blank')">View Error Details</button>
                    """)

flash_message = Markup(f"""
                <div>
                    <strong>{operation_title}</strong><br/> {operation_summary_message} {open_errors_view_button_html}<br/><br/>
                </div>
                """)

flash_message2 = Markup(f"""
                <div>
                    <strong>{operation_title}</strong><br/> {operation_summary_message}<br/><br/>
                </div>
                """)

flash_message3 = Markup(f"""
                <div>
                    {open_errors_view_button_html}<br/><br/>
                </div>
                """)
return flash_message

when I attempt to flash this:
flash_message = Markup(f"""
            <div>
                <strong>{operation_title}</strong><br/> {operation_summary_message} {open_errors_view_button_html}<br/><br/>
            </div>
            """)

It just doesn't show.
